# Multidimensional Array reference instance js

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, reference, instance-variables

```
function obtainArray(n){
    var array = [];
    var row   = [];
    for(var x = 0; x < n; ++x){ row.push(x); }
    for(var x = 0; x < n; ++x){ array.push(row); }
    return array;
    }
            array = obtainArray(8);
            array[1][1] = 'This only must display in array[1][1]';
            console.log(array);
```

I think the problem is because i´m row like a reference and i want use like a instance.

Answer (score 1):

You need for every row an empty object. Otherwise you keep the reference to the single row in all pushed rows.

```js
function obtainArray(n) {
    var array = [],
        row,
        x, y;
    for (x = 0; x < n; ++x) {
        row = [];                  // initialize with empty array
        for (y = 0; y < n; ++y) {
            row.push(y);           // fill array
        }
        array.push(row);           // push array
    }
    return array;
}

array = obtainArray(8);
array[1][1] = 'This only must display in array[1][1]';
console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A single loop approach with pushing a *copy* of row with [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

> The **`slice()`** method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object selected from begin to end (end not included). The original array will not be modified.

```js
function obtainArray(n) {
    var array = [],
        row = [],
        x;

    for (x = 0; x < n; ++x) {
        row.push(x);             // fill array
    }
    for (x = 0; x < n; ++x) {
        array.push(row.slice()); // push copy
    }
    return array;
}

array = obtainArray(8);
array[1][1] = 'This only must display in array[1][1]';
console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank´s Nina.But dont exists other way? I think the double loop is unnecesary if you have only repeat a row.

Comment: @Yonkykong, you could use a copy of row, but it works only with primitive values. if you have objects inside, the reference is copied and points to the same object.